# Backbone: Cross-View Event Binding with listenTo()

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I know the proper way to bind events in Backbone is to use `listenTo()` rather than `on()`, as described in this [blog post](http://ozkatz.github.io/avoiding-common-backbonejs-pitfalls.html).

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
}
```

But what if you need to bind events across views?

Up to now, I've been using Backbone's global pubsub:

```
Backbone.on('custom:event', this.handleEvent);
```

That works alright, but I've yet to find a clean way to unbind a global event like this. For instance, if the view is replaced by a new instance, I can do this:

```
Backbone.off('custom:event').on('custom:event', this.handleEvent);
```

That works as long as nothing else is also listening, but certainly isn't ideal.

I'd prefer to use `listenTo()`, but don't know how to do this without specifying the view instance that will trigger the event. I suppose I could inject it when the listener is created, but that requires making sure the publisher is already instantiated and seems fragile.

Has anyone come up with a good way to bind events between views?

(In case it matters, the views aren't related -- a.k.a. child view and parent view.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`listenTo`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L212) is little more than this:

```
Events.listenTo = function(obj, name, callback) {
  //...
  obj.on(name, callback, this);
  //...
};
```

Similarly, [`stopListening`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L151) is a bunch of bookkeeping wrapped around `off`. That means that you can `listenTo` anything that hs the usual `on` and `off` methods:

```
this.listenTo(Backbone, 'custom:event', this.handleEvent, this);
```

Comment: That's awesome - thank you. Hadn't occurred to me to use the global object as the first argument. Solves the problem perfectly, thanks again